# replacing backslash on each special character using bash script

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace each special character in string with backslash:
`This is the test st&ri(g` > `This is the test st\&ri\(g`

I tried:

```
echo "This is test (" | sed -r "s/[&()'^]/ /g"

echo "Hello World ( This is our new special ) and singlq quote character '" |
    sed -e 's/[(]/\(/g' -e 's/[)]/\)/g' -e "s/[']/\\'/g"
```

How to do this using sed command using regular expression ?

Comment: What sed commands have you tried? What is your definition of "special character"?

Comment: special characters like ( ) ' ^ at least these characters.  echo "This is test (" | sed -r "s/[&()'^]/  /g"  what I want is, write regex with characters and if any one of these characters match then prefix with "\" on that character.

Comment: Or I need to loop each character and if certain characters match then add backslash before that special character set ? cannot we do this using SED command ?

Comment: I think I am atleast near to this. I need to give multiple -e commands. like below
echo "Hello World ( This is our new special ) and singlq quote character '" | sed -e 's/[(]/\\(/g'  -e 's/[)]/\\)/g' -e "s/[']/\\'/g" 
to get the text like  Hello World \( This is our new special \) and singlq quote character '

Comment: Your question was collecting downvotes and close votes because you hadn't shown any attempt to solve the problem yourself so I copy/pasted the attempts you mentioned in comments into your question to hopefully stop the flood. In future when posting questions always include a [mcve] with sample input, expected output, your attempt to solve it, a statement  of requirements, and a statement of what was wrong with your attempts. See [ask].

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton, this answer which you provided is helpful for me. I understand in the replace string i need to use "&" so that it will consider all those characters mentioned in regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'This is the test st&ri(g' | sed 's/[&()'\''^]/\\&/g'
This is the test st\&ri\(g
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29764510)

Comment: @INDRAJITH of course it provides an answer to the question. Can't imagine why you;d think it doesn't.

Comment: I preferred if you can elaborate more on the answer without just posting codeblock.